# windows could not start the mysql service on local computer error 1067

Tags: mysql, windows-7

I am facing the following error when I try to restart the MySQL service after an unexpected shutdown of the database server.

> Windows could not start the MySQL service on Local Computer. Error
>   1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

When I check the mysql_error.err log file under the XAMPP MySql data folder, the log details are

> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using
>   innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be
>   removed in future releases, together with the option
>   innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>   2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count
>   buffer pool pages 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB
>   memory heap is disabled 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions 2015-11-10
>   15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used 2015-11-10
>   15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>   2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32
>   instructions 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing
>   buffer pool, size = 16.0M 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Completed initialization of buffer pool 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348
>   [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda. 2015-11-10
>   15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
>   2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>   2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB
>   (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number
>   1835027 2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s)
>   not yet started 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is
>   disabled. 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP:
>   '::'. 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>   2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready
>   for connections. Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306 
>   mariadb.org binary distribution 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note]
>   C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0
>   events 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5732 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread
>   exiting. 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>   2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log
>   sequence number 1835037 2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note]
>   C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

**Mysql Version 5.5**

Comment: First upgrade to windows 10 windows 7 is not longer supported with updates, second look at the time of the computer and see that windows finds a timeserver. The log only shows that everything is in order, but mysql 5.5 is old very old and you should also upgrade mysql when you are at it

Comment: @nbk since it is a server machine I don't have permission to do the OS update. Maybe I will try with the latest Mysql version.

Comment: that is a problem, but frst look after the system time, this could resolve your issues.

Comment: @nbk sure let me try and get back to you

Comment: You may find this URL useful.  https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-error-1067-the-process-terminated-unexpectedly/